# jMeter signing URL and hash

Tags: rest, jmeter

We are working on a time critical task and are required to write performance script for a REST WS using jMeter.

The REST API takes an auth header. This auth header has:

1. A signed URL (of the REST API itself).
2. A hash of everything sent in POST body.

We want a jMeter script so that it can:

1. Read the contents of the POST body from say an excel sheet or from a java method etc. as the content of post body has to change per login.
2. Create the hash of POST body everytime the content of body changes and use this hash in the auth header.
3. Sign the URL and use it in auth header.

My questions are:

1. Is all the above possible to achieve? This is the minimum i want to know so that I know if I have to spend any more time on this.
2. What is the best way to do this?
3. I am assuming that the content of POST body and auth header both can be dynamic. Is this correct? If not, we cannot write this script at all.

The only jMeter i know is what is here in the comment. It would be impossible to get all my answers in the given time.

Any answers, help, pointers would be helpful.

Appreciate you reading this - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, possible. We have done similar things.
2. Two possible options are:

   - use a beanshell pre-processor
   - use a custom function

We opted for the latter as it used memory better

and 3. Yes, you can pass in vars to make each request different. One way to source data is using a CSV Data Config control.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. This was helpful. I never realized I didn't respond to you.